# The argument type 'Iterable<Future<SubwayStation>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<SubwayStation>'

Tags: flutter

```
class Stations extends ChangeNotifier {
  StationListState state = StationListState(loading: false, stations: []);

  Future<void> getMachedStations() async {
    state = state.copyWith(loading: true);
    notifyListeners();

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> aroundStations =
        await FindNearStation().getLocation();
    print(aroundStations.length);

    var subwaysRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('subways');


    var stations = aroundStations.map((searchedElement) async {
      String subwayStationName = yuk(searchedElement['subwayStationName']);

      try {
        print(' ::::: ${searchedElement['line']}');
        var lineRef = await subwaysRef
            .doc(searchedElement['line'])
            .collection(subwayStationName)
            .get();

        return SubwayStation.fromDoc(lineRef.docs[0]);
      } catch (e) {
        state = state.copyWith(loading: false);
      }
    });

    state = state.copyWith(loading: false, stations: stations); // <-- Error (stations : stations)
  }
}
```

I try to get the returned list I get the error:
The argument type 'Iterable<Future>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You made the method passed to `map` `async`, so it returns a `Future` instead of what you expect. You either don't use `map` or you wait for each of the `Future`s to complete. The latter is probably easier with the following code added just before you call to `copyWith`:

```dart
var awaitedStations = await Future.wait(stations);
```

---

Full code:

```dart
class Stations extends ChangeNotifier {
  StationListState state = StationListState(loading: false, stations: []);

  Future<void> getMachedStations() async {
    state = state.copyWith(loading: true);
    notifyListeners();

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> aroundStations =
        await FindNearStation().getLocation();
    print(aroundStations.length);

    var subwaysRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('subways');


    var stations = aroundStations.map((searchedElement) async {
      String subwayStationName = yuk(searchedElement['subwayStationName']);

      try {
        print(' ::::: ${searchedElement['line']}');
        var lineRef = await subwaysRef
            .doc(searchedElement['line'])
            .collection(subwayStationName)
            .get();

        return SubwayStation.fromDoc(lineRef.docs[0]);
      } catch (e) {
        state = state.copyWith(loading: false);
      }
    });

    var awaitedStations = await Future.wait<SubwayStation>(stations);    

    state = state.copyWith(loading: false, stations: awaitedStations);
  }
}
```